# Online IDE that you can share a private url for invitees to view

Tags: ide, nitrousio, koding, codio

I thought for sure this would be a normal thing, but while reading about Nitrous, Koding, Codio, etc, I couldn't quite find it.

I want to build a site in an online IDE and share a private url with people to use it. I don't want the public to see it, only those that I invite via email or authentication or ???

I thought Codio did it, but it says that no-one can see a private url. And everyone can see a public url. Not what I want.

Comment: being able to "share" a URL with people outside your local network by default means the URL is public and not private :)  only other way to control access is to IP restrict or add username and passwords.

Comment: I just want to do testing. Codio says you can have private URLs with their pay accounts. These are not local, they are online with xxxxx.codio.io.app/xxxx. It gave me some message when I first changed to private, but then I am still able to access from any device. Might be a better question for Codio, but was wondering if anyone else had experience with an IDE where I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set http basic auth on rails and django applications on [Nitrous](https://www.nitrous.io).

Here's a detailed article explaining how to set http basic auth on a Rails and Django application:

https://community.nitrous.io/docs/setting-up-basic-auth-on-nitrous-preview-urls

Example Rails controller code:

```rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   http_basic_authenticate_with name: "foo", password: "bar", except: :index

   def index
     render text: "This text can be seen by everyone."
   end

   def edit
     render text: "You can only view this if you know the username and password."
   end
end
```